# Inserting values in the table

Tags: sqlplus

I'm trying to insert values into my table, but it keep saying 'missing comma'.
This is the datatypes for the attributes

```
CREATE TABLE DDR_Customer
(customer_name VARCHAR2(30),  
 customer_ID NUMBER(5), 
 city VARCHAR2(20), 
 street VARCHAR2(20),
 prov CHAR(2),
 postal_code VARCHAR2(6),
 phone_number VARCHAR2(15), 
 email VARCHAR2(50),
 credit_number NUMBER(20), 
 credit_type VARCHAR2(2), 
 credit_card_expiry VARCHAR2(15));
```

This is what I'm trying to insert.

```
INSERT INTO DDR_Customer (customer_name, customer_ID, city, street, prov, postal_code, phone_number, email, credit_number, credit_type, credit_card_expiry)
VALUES ('Jenna Lee', 12345, 'Calgary', '9 Street', 'AB', 'L9L9L9', '403.892.8677', 'Jennalee@gmail.com', 4324 2424 2222 2222, 'AX', '10-Dec-19');
```

Comment: There should not be any spaces in the credit number you enter.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal but this is my constraint for credit number.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CARD_NUM_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(credit_number,'[0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}'))

Comment: What happens if you were to remove spaces in credit card number? If insert fails, either change your credit_number to varchar(20) or such, or move your constraint to the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at example here: https://rextester.com/PQY62260

If you were to keep credit_number NUMBER(20) with check constraint like you have, your insert with fail even when you have or don't have spaces in your credit card number.

If you remove your constraint, insert will operate correctly. If you keep the constraint, change credit_number to VARCHAR(20) and then single-quote credit card number with spaces and then your insert will work correctly.

Comment: I changed it to VARCHAR2(20) but it says, unmatched parentheses in regular expression

Comment: Can you copy and paste create table and insert statement from example link I’ve provided?